# Can't fetch data from NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, google-places-api, nsurlrequest

I am fetching result from google place search url, if I search for "Newyork", everything works fine. But if I give "New york", the result json is different and I can't take it in NSData.
This is the url I am using:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=New york&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY

I am using below code to fetch the data:

```
NSURL *googleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];  //url is above url
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data;

NSError    *error;

data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: [NSURLRequest
                                                 requestWithURL: googleURL]   returningResponse: &response error: &error];


NSLog(@"data %@",data);   // but I am getting null here
```

How to overcome this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `url` is:

```
NSString *url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=New york&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY";
```

Try using this:

```
NSURL *googleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

This will format the string for URLs containing spaces.  To confirm it is working, print it out to the console.

```
NSLog(@"URL with Percent Escapes: %@", [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

It should return something like this (I believe the percent escape for a space is `%20`).

```
URL with Percent Escapes: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=New%20york&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY
```